# Python Django: Pillow installation works but django doesn't recognise it

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am learning to write a basic online shop webapp with Django. I am follow instructions from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZ3DhppbUnM&t=269s, all seems to be fine but I found myself in a loop. When running

```
C:\Users\Llewellyn\myshop>python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
shop.Product.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".

C:\Users\Llewellyn\myshop>
```

Then after installation in PyCharm project terminal

```
(myshop) C:\Users\Llewellyn\myshop>pip install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
  Downloading Pillow-7.0.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (2.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.0 MB 1.7 MB/s
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-7.0.0

(myshop) C:\Users\Llewellyn\myshop>
```

and rerunning `python manage.py makemigrations` in commandprompt

I get the same error? Which is confusing because I just installed the package?

The complete problem..'

```
C:\Users\Llewellyn\myshop>python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
shop.Product.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".

C:\Users\Llewellyn\myshop>python -m pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (7.0.0)

C:\Users\Llewellyn\myshop>python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
shop.Product.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".

C:\Users\Llewellyn\myshop>
```

Please help

Comment: you can have two python installed and you run django with one python but you installed Pillow in other python. You can try `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: I did use ``python -m pip install ...`` the problem remains

Comment: as sain @COB you run django in normal console but you install pillow in virtualenv `(myshop)`. You have do to all in normal console or do all in virtualenv. Don't mix it because virtualenv install it in separated folders and normal python has no access to this folder.

Answer (score 2):

You installed Pillow inside of your virtual env (see the `(myshop)` before the location) but then it looks like you are trying to use it outside of you virtual env

Comment: I probably sound like a novice.. but how would I get into the correct virtual env in command prompt?

Comment: the Pycharm terminal is in same virtual env, you can just run your `python manage.py makemigrations` from there

Comment: Thanx so much.. It worked, for my own learning, how would I be able to direct myself to the correct virtual env in cmdprompt

Comment: @LlewellynHattingh virtualenv should create folder with separated python and with program `activate` (`activate.bat` on Windows) to activate virtualenv - and you have to run it everytime when you start working with virtualenv.

Comment: `pip install virtualenv`
`cd myshop`
`virtualenv env`

Comment: Awesome thanx so much for the help. Stay safe